# How to find reason behind changed state of virtual machines?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, eventviewer

I am working in **Windows** Virtual machines which were part of Hyper-V setup. It was in running state but now I see it state as "**OFF**", I have manually changed the state to "**Running**" but I want to know the root cause.

Please help to find the logs.

I searched in Hyper-V event logs in the Event Viewer under **“Applications and Services Logs**”, “Microsoft”, “Windows. But unable to find the root cause

Comment: version of windows? are the machines set to start automatically on boot? (aka did it experience a restart?)

Comment: Windows 10 enterprise . Machine did not restart